# jQuery find 2nd Table add TD

Tags: jquery, find, addition, prepend

I am missing something pretty simple here, I need to add a td in the 2nd table.  I cannot get it and I know its something simple.  I shortened it up for intense and purposes:

```
<div id="content_area">
 <table>
    <table></table>
 </table>
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td> // I want to add another TD before this
        <table></table>
        <table></table>
      </td>  
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>


 $('#content_area').find('table:eq(1)').find('td').before('<td>Data</td>');
```

Comment: [Intents and purposes](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/all-intents-and-purposes.html)...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 $('#content_area').find('>table:eq(1)').find('td').before('<td>Data</td>');
```

If you don't use the ">" the second table will be the one into the first table.

Comment: The `.find('td')` will find *all* nested `td` elements, and add a new `td` before each one. The markup doesn't show any other `td` elements, but I'm guessing that's because OP simplified it. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#content_area table:nth-child(2) tr').prepend('<td>Data</td>');
```

Comment: I like your `nth-child` approach better, but if you don't use `>`, you'll get two results from the selector. The second will be the `table:nth-child(2)` from the pair of nested tables. Though they don't show any `tr` elements, I'm guessing that's because OP simplified his markup.